# Asp.Net Session Object Priority

Tags: asp.net, session, caching, iis

We're currently building an application in which we rely heavily in storing data in sessions for each individual user. We cannot use Cache since these data are specific to users, and re-querying data when we need it is an expensive process: so the solution was to query once from the DB, store into session, and then keep using it until the session ends. A concern I have is how IIS handles these sessions when too much session data is stored in memory.

1. when does it know when to clear session data?
2. how does it determine which session variable to clear out first if memory runs low?
3. Is there a way to set priories to individual session objects: clear less prioritized data first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is using `InProc` sessions whereby the sessions are stored in the memory of the current worker process.

> 1. when does it know when to clear session data?

`InProc` sessions are cleared as you might expect when zero requests have been made for the session for the length of the configured session timeout.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30"/>
```

However this is not an exact duration. The session will be cleared after the timeout but only when a cleanup is triggered by the internal mechanics of the session handler. Each session doesn't have it's own timer polling for a session timeout. It will get done, when it's optimal for it to be done.

You should also note that since worker processes are regularly recycled any and all sessions stored in that process will be deleted. `InProc` sessions will also not work in web farms since each request could be handled by a different machine.

> 2. how does it determine which session variable to clear out first if memory runs low?

It doesn't. It will simply shift to using virtual memory like any other windows process and as such you would now be backing your sessions with disk based virtual memory instead of chip based memory. Eventually the whole process would get recycled and everything would be wiped as per 1.

> 3. Is there a way to set priories to individual session objects: clear less prioritized data first

Not out of the box with `InProc`. Ultimately the session is just storing objects so you could run your own cleanup according to whatever makes sense for your app by simply tagging your `InProc` objects with some kind of value. But you'll quickly end up simply replicating the features already available and probably not doing it as well as MS.

Check out [System.Web.SessionState namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.aspx) for some options but bear in mind that by using `InProc` you are always going to be held to ransom by worker process recycling which can be triggered by many different things: antivirus software resetting the timestamps on web.config files for example.

For a viable and popular alternative to `InProc` sessions, check out [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Comment: Rism, thank you for the information. You mentioned that the worker process will backup the session data in disk if it determines it needs to, is it then safe to assume that session data will not disappear unless the timeout is reached, a process recycle is triggered or user closes the browser? My worry is that when the application goes into production, we're estimating about 700 concurrent users, and with that volume  sessions may get cleared unexpectedly due to low memory.

Comment: It wont "back it up" it will just spill over as per normal virtual paging etc. I would NOT rely on `InProc` at all. If the worker process recycles just once with 700 concurrent users, that's 700 sessions lost. Bang! In one hit you just %^$& 700 users off. Why would you do that to them and yourselves?